# How to apply a function to the output of tail -f?

Tags: linux, tail

I have a log file that continuously gets updated. I can view the file with `tail -f` and see all the changes as they come in. However, there is an issue - the text contains the characters \n instead of newlines. I would like to change the characters \n into actual newlines. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: What? Do you mean it contains the characters backslash and lowercase-latin-letter N instead of a linefeed? That's a problem with the writer and not with `tail -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me:

```
tail -f logfile | sed 's/\\n/\
/g'
```